# KeyCloak and Spring Security, how to restrict data partially

Tags: spring, security, keycloak

I have the following use case:

Users have general roles like:

- devteam

this will give them access to several functions in the backend.

But additionally they also have a non-fix set of roles which may be added during time. Something like

- devteam-europe (composite role to devteam role)
- devteam-asia (composite role to devteam role)
  etc.

Now I want the backend functions to behave like this:
Access function if role is "devteam": that works :)

But in the underlying sql queries I want to restrict the resultset depending on other roles. So devteam-europe will get other results as devteam-asia.

The big problem is, that in my applicaton each team has a uuid, while in KeyCloak the role has a speaking name. So I need to map somehow

devteam-europe to my internal UUID!

I could add attributes or properties to the role in KeyCloak, but they don't seem to be available in the JWT.

In my real world project it's a multi-tenancy applicatio with various entities.
Do you have any ideas, on how to to accomplish this?

Cheers Maik

Answer (score 0):

> I could add attributes or properties to the role in KeyCloak, but they don't seem to be available in the JWT.

In the corresponding client, you must define a Token Mapper which will tell Keycloak what source (in your case attribute or property) will map to which target (key => value) in your JWT.